# GAE redirecting to http://localhost:8080/_ah/null after using logging form locally

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I developed a java GAE application, then when locally i try to login as an administrator with url localhost:8080/_ah/login i got the login form which is correct.

Then i check the login as administrator checkbox and try to loggin.
The form is posted correctly :
email:test@example.com
isAdmin:on
continue:null
action:Log In

And then the following request is launched :
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/_ah/**null**
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found

Strange isn't it ?

By the way localhost:8080/_ah/admin works fine and i have a spring security configuration to allow requests proceeding with no special case for _ah/login request

Any idea would be appreciated :=)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing strange about it. You didn't provide a (proper) redirect url when sending the user to `/_ah/login`.

Have a look at your form post parameters

> email:test@example.com isAdmin:on continue:null action:Log In

Here continue is null, therefor you will be redirected to null.

Your Login URL should look something like this:

> http://localhost:8080/_ah/login?continue=../

or

> http://localhost:8080/_ah/login?continue=http://www.google.com

Okay, a URL escape would've been nice, but this works for demonstration purposes.

If you use the `UserService` you should provide a redirect URL in your call to `userService.createLoginURL(thisURL)` (see [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/)).  If you provide null there you will be redirected to `null`. When showing the login the parameter list must contain the `continue` parameter or null will be assumed.

Comment: Actually i did not call userService.createLoginURL because i did not developed a personal login page. The login form is automatically generated by GAE when i call localhost:8080/_ah/login.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you call the login URL you should provide a redirect URL or you will end up on that null page. I might be able to help more if you provide anything to go with. Your question is a bit meager. Some code maybe?

Comment: @john i generified my answer so it's a better match for your question.

Comment: I thank you for the answer but actually the problem was not with my code. First i tried to create a brand new guestbook application from the maven archetype. It didn't work. So i tried updating my GAE sdk version from 1.9.19 to 1.9.28 and it worked. Hope it can help someone else.